# Enter date and save in Database and print back in same format

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I want to Enter Date in Form in html and save that in database,and show that value that I exactly entered in Form.

SQL stores in yyyy-mm-dd format but i want to show in d/m/y format

Comment: Please show some effort in solving this. Can you please post the code you are trying to use?

Comment: If your dates are in a `date` (or similar) datatype, the values are not stored in any format at all. Format is only applied when visualising the value (i.e. showing it on screen)

Comment: Have you already taken a look at [DateTime::format](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use date format to display date in the required formats.
If still you want date to be stored in the table as d/m/y format, then you can change the type of the field that holds the value from datetime to varchar.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Storing dates in a varchar column is terrible advice.